# How to create a DebuggerVisualizer for build in generic classes or arrays

Tags: visual-studio, generics, debuggervisualizer

I am using VisualStudio DebuggerVisualizer for many of my own classes by applying the DebuggerVisualizer attribute to those classes. Now I would also like to show something like `List<MyClass>` with a single DialogDebuggerVisualizer. Of course I can open such a list in QuickWatch and view each item, but the whole list doesn't show the "magnifying glass", with which in turn I could show my DialogDebuggerVisualizer. I cannot add the DebuggerVisualizer attribute to `List<MyClass>`, nor can I add an extension property to `List<MyClass>` (which would return a DebuggerVisualizer attributed object). The only way I found so long is having some static method which takes `List<MyClass>` as a parameter and returns an object with the DebuggerVisualizer attribute set. This is sometimes cumbersome when you are deep down in a hierarchy of objects. Is there a better solution?